# Apache auto-crash at startup after a bsod, fault module StackHash_0a9e

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, windows-registry, crash, bsod

This problem happens after a window crash, I have tried everything but no luck, please help!

**Problem Details**

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.2.22.0
  Application Timestamp:    4f242d7a
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_0a9e
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 01f2a689
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

On Windows 7 64x

**Have tried**

- Disk check on system driver and the driver has httpd.exe, no bad
  files, no bad sectors found
- SFC (System File Check), no problem found
- System restore, going back to the point when httpd starts up no
  problem and windows not crashed, not work
- Scan Registry and fix issues, not work
- Download and re-install the program of httpd, also tried latest
  version, not work

I'm totally lost at this time, don't even know where possibly the problem resides, any suggestion except re-install windows are appreciated!

Comment: capture a crash dump and send it to the Apache developers : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981, never knew a dump file can be created on application crash, by far the only useful information I got here, thank you!

Comment: @magicandre1981, I had enabled localdumps followed the link, no error window pops again when starting httpd.exe now, but there is also no dump file, tried a few times, not a dump file in the folder I set or the default folder as of the article, any thoughts?

Comment: Got dump files, somehow it only generates when I run the wrapper application ampps.exe